# is it possible to ignore the error and continue execute update in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table stored all my project rss channel url, now I found some url end with '/' but some sub url are not. I my app I have to handle this situation in everywhere. Then I want to store all the sub url link without the last '/', if the url end with '/', I want to delete the end of '/'. I have write the update sql command like this:

```
UPDATE rss_sub_source 
SET sub_url = SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1) 
WHERE sub_url LIKE '%/';
```

when I execute the sql:

```
SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_sub_url"
  Detail: Key (sub_url)=(https://physicsworld.com/feed) already exists.
```

the error shows that some url without '/' have already exists. when I update wht end with '/' url, it will conflict with the exists one because I add an uniq constraint. There table contains thousands of url, update one by one obviously impossible. So I want to ignore and jump to update the url if it did not obey the uniq constraint, only update the success record. Finnaly delete the end with '/' record.

Is it possible to ignore the update error events in PostgreSQL? if not what should I do to make all rss url did not end with '/'?

Comment: Are you trying to find the duplicates and only update the rest of records?

Comment: I have updated the record one by one.@Bijujose if I encount conflicts, I delete the record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if such a `sub_url` already exists:

```
UPDATE rss_sub_source 
SET sub_url = SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1) 
WHERE sub_url LIKE '%/' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM rss_sub_source 
  WHERE sub_url = SUBSTRING
                  (
                    sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1
                  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you have to find the duplicate then delete those records first and then do the update.

```
create table rss_sub_source (
  id int,
  sub_url varchar(100)
  );
  
  insert into rss_sub_source 
  select 1,'https://www.google.com/'
  union all
  select 2,'https://www.msn.com/'
  union all
  select 3,'https://www.google.com/'
  union all 
  select 4,'https://www.gmail.com'

--find dupicates and delete

delete  FROM rss_sub_source r
using (
select SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1),
       row_number() OVER(partition by SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1,CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1) 
       order by id asc) rnk,
       id
from rss_sub_source
  )  x where x.id=r.id
 and rnk>1;
 
 select * FROM rss_sub_source;
 
 --final update 
 UPDATE rss_sub_source 
SET sub_url = SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1) 
WHERE sub_url LIKE '%/';

select * FROM rss_sub_source;
```